# RollingFileAppender is not creating log file

Tags: tomcat, configuration, log4j, configuration-files

I have following `log4j.xml` file for my tomcat web application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
<!-- Appenders -->
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
                        value="%-5p: %d{ABSOLUTE} [%t] %c:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="errorFileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="threshold" value="error" />
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <param name="FileNamePattern" 
                value="${catalina.base}/logs/error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log"/>
        <param name="ActiveFileName" value="${catalina.base}/logs/error.log"/>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
                        value="%-5p: %d{ABSOLUTE} [%t] %c:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<!-- Application Loggers -->
<!-- some loggers -->

<!-- Root Logger -->
<root>
    <priority value="warn" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="errorFileAppender" />
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

With this configuration everything is logging to `catalina.out`.
But my purpose was also to log all errors to separate `error.log` which will be rolled hourly.
When I was using `FileAppender` `error.log` file is created and populated with errors logs. But when I switched to `RollingFileAppender` `error.log` file is not even created.

Please help me with this configuration. I can not spot mistake here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is, that I used `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender` and not `org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender`